# C#, XAML, WPF: Best way to do complex binding including textboxes and checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have two textboxes and one checkbox (and other similar cases), where I want the underlying dataobjects (two ints) which my program will later be using to be equal to what's in the textboxes unless the checkbox is checked, they should in that case be 0 and Int.max respectively.

What's the best way to do this with WPF bindings? I assume I have to use multibindings somehow? The other possibility would be to chain values together if that's even possible (?), i.e. checkbox.IsChecked binds to textBox.Text via some custom converter, which binds to the underlying dataobject.

How would you do this? Seems to me that multibindings make sense where multiple things affect one other thing cumulatively somehow and that chaining makes more sense wherever possible, right? I have one case which is similar to the above but also includes a Slider.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) approach. Build a ViewModel that implements the logic you need:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _min;
    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set
        {
            _min = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Min");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActualMin");
        }
    }

    private int _max;
    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set
        {
            _max = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Max");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActualMax");
        }
    }

    private bool _useMinMax;
    public bool UseMinMax
    {
        get { return _useMinMax; }
        set
        {
            _useMinMax = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UseMinMax");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActualMin");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActualMax");
        }
    }

    public int ActualMin
    {
        get { return _useMinMax ? _min : 0; }
    }

    public int ActualMax
    {
        get { return _useMinMax ? _max : int.MaxValue; }
    }

}
```

Bind your textboxes to `Min` and `Max`, and bind the `CheckBox` to `UseMinMax`. Then use `ActualMin` and `ActualMax` to get the actual values to use.

Comment: Your min and max also need to raise the OnPropertyChanged for ActualMin and ActualMax

Comment: This is supposed to be the VM class, right? What happened to the model? Shouldn't _min, _max etc be in the model according to MVVM?

Comment: @Mårten, the model can be whatever you like. I don't know what your actual model looks like, so I just used 2 ints...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the MVVM approach. In the view-model layer you may put whatever logic you want to make the UI behaving according your goals. Simple, fast and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MVVM. Here you have it, on video plus free:

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=288066